# Reduce number of ticks on x-axis where labels are date

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib, am creating a graph using matplotlib.plot, x-axis is labelled with dates and Y with numbers

```
x = ['2018-08-17', '2018-08-20', '2018-08-21', '2018-08-22', '2018-08-23', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-27', '2018-08-28', '2018-08-29', '2018-08-30', '2018-08-31','2018-11-29', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-04', '2018-12-05']

y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

I am converting these string dates in real date using below code

```
xdates = [dt.strptime(dstr,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for dstr in x]
```

after converting it to dates, I tried

```
plt.xticks(range(0,len(xdates),2),xdates[1::2],rotation=50)

plt.plot(xdates,y)
```

but its doing nothing.

### I want to put less ticks and labels on x-axis. Suppose there are 15 dates but I want only 7 or 8 dates to appear on x axis. How can I achieve this?

Below is the method am using to create the trend graph

```
def _create_trend_graph(self,element):
    if(len(self.processed_data)!=0):

        x_axis = element['X-Axis']
        y_axis = []
        plt.xticks(rotation=70)
        plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10001,element['Range']))
        #plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 101,10))
        figure = plt.gcf()  # get current figure
        figure.set_size_inches(14, 8)
        for key in element.iterkeys():
            if key.lower().startswith("y-axis"):
                self.null_index = len(self.processed_data[element[key]])
                for index in range(len(self.processed_data[element[key]])):
                    if self.processed_data[element[key]][index] == 'Null':
                        self.null_index = index
                        break
                plt.plot(self.processed_data[x_axis][:self.null_index], list(map(float, self.processed_data[element[key]][:self.null_index])))
                y_axis = y_axis + [str(element[key])]
        #plt.legend(y_axis, prop={'size': 16})
        plt.legend(y_axis)
        plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10.0
        plt.savefig(self.monitored_folder+element['Title'], bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 100)
        plt.close()
        self._add_image_to_body(str(element['Title']), str(element['height']), str(element['width']))
    else:
        self._create_NA()
```

Here element['X-Axis'] we have dates as for example,

['2018-08-17', '2018-08-20', '2018-08-21', '2018-08-22', '2018-08-23', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-27', '2018-08-28', '2018-08-29', '2018-08-30', '2018-08-31','2018-11-29', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-04', '2018-12-05']

and in y-axis we are putting numbers. So the issue is actually we are getting a large number of dates in element['X-Axis'], so its just making the xaxis very crowded. also the number of dates may increase in future.

One solution is to just increase the size of the graph but this is the last thing we want to do. Am unable to attach image as I don't have much reputation.
How else can I show you the image @ImportanceofbeingErnest

after generating the graph we are passing it to below method

```
def _add_image_to_body(self,image_name,height,width):
    attachment = self.mail.Attachments.Add(self.monitored_folder+image_name+'.png')
    attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", image_name.replace(' ','_'))
    self.html += ("<img src=\"cid:" + image_name.replace(' ', '_') + '\"' + " height="+height+" width="+width+"><br><br>")
```

Comment: Matplotlib will not put 15 ticks on an axis, unless you specifically ask it to do so. So there is something in your code that makes this happen, which should be removed/replaced. But it's not clear from the question what that could be. See [mcve].

Comment: have updated the question, using xticks method before plotting, I tried to put xticks method after plotting as well, but it didn't helped

Comment: The `xticks` is not particularly helpful. I think you used it to workaround a different problem, which I sketched in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are running into is that matplotlib's `AutoDateLocator` currently ticks every 29th of a month, such that its label will overlapp with the first of the next month.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt

x = ['2018-08-17', '2018-08-20', '2018-08-21', '2018-08-22', '2018-08-23', '2018-08-24', 
     '2018-08-27', '2018-08-28', '2018-08-29', '2018-08-30', '2018-08-31','2018-11-29', 
     '2018-11-30', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-04', '2018-12-05']
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

xdates = [dt.strptime(dstr,'%Y-%m-%d') for dstr in x]

plt.plot(xdates,y)

plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=60, ha="right")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

This can be considered as a bug. But it is fixed in the current development version, such that from matplotlib 3.1 this problem should not occur any more.

A workaround is to define a ticker yourself that would tick each first and 15th of a month.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime as dt

x = ['2018-08-17', '2018-08-20', '2018-08-21', '2018-08-22', '2018-08-23', '2018-08-24', 
     '2018-08-27', '2018-08-28', '2018-08-29', '2018-08-30', '2018-08-31','2018-11-29', 
     '2018-11-30', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-04', '2018-12-05']
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

xdates = [dt.strptime(dstr,'%Y-%m-%d') for dstr in x]

plt.plot(xdates,y)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator((1,15)))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=60, ha="right")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: yes you almost got it right :-) Thanks for being so elabborative... the only change i need is that suppose if there are 20 dates in xdates, then there should be 20 ticks on xaxis but lesser label say 10 or 12 so that the xaxis doesn't look too crowded. The code you provided above is also removing the ticks. In other words you can say that I just want to hide the alternate label

Comment: In the answer above the ticks are completely independent of the actual data. If you want to tick those dates that you have in you list, part of the axis will be very crowded, part will be empty; and even if you only show every second tick with a label, they would still overlap. I'm hence not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Am sorry if am not able to articulate myself clearly, am updating the above question with the method through which am generating the trend graph and the image of graph am getting... please have a look at the question again.. may be it help..

Comment: well, am unable to add image to the questions as I don't have 10 reputation.. am just giving the method..

Comment: one last thing...can we add start date and end date in 
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator((1,15)))

Comment: No, actually you can't. In that case, you would rather create a list of dates you want to tick manually.